# Unable to set password in MySQL installation

Tags: mysql, password

I have tried multiple times uninstalling MySQL but every time it skips setting up the password for the host. I need a password as I need it connect it to Python.

This is the output after running `sudo mysql_secure_installation`:

```
There are three levels of password validation policy:
LOW    Length >= 8
MEDIUM Length >= 8, numeric, mixed case, and special characters
STRONG Length >= 8, numeric, mixed case, special characters and dictionary file

Please enter 0 = LOW, 1 = MEDIUM and 2 = STRONG: 0

Skipping password set for root as authentication with auth_socket is used by default.
If you would like to use password authentication instead, this can be done with the "ALTER_USER" command.
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html#alter-user-password-management for more information.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be a bug. In the earlier, if we change `auth_socket` to `mysql_native_password` for `root` before we use `mysql_secure_installation`, `mysql_secure_installation` allows us to change root's password.

However, now, I have to change `auth_socket` to `mysql_native_password` and use `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx'` to set a password for `root` and only then I can use `mysql_native_password` to change root's password.

To reproduce,

1. After install `mysql-server`, run

   ```bash
   sudo mysql -u root mysql
   ```
2. Execute the following SQL statements:

   ```
   UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```

   And (but this should not be necessary)

   ```
   ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   ```
3. Run `sudo mysql_secure_installation`, and then set root's password.

Comment: Thanks so much! This helped 1+

Answer (score 0):

You can login to mysql on the physical machine (or via ssh). Then inside the database use the ALTER USER command to enable password authentication and set the password.

Example:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit I am new to the Linux os